# What is the difference between Amazon MWS and Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have confusion in understanding the Web services provided by Amazon site. I want to know the difference between Amazon MWS and Amazon AWS web services.

Does anyone knows the difference and can clarify which one is better to export an ecommerce site item to Amazon store?

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) is a cloud computing platform that allows people to purchase many different types of computing-related resources -- that physically reside in Amazon's datacenters.  These include infrastructural resources such as as servers, storage, and networking, as well as services such as database and bulk-email.

[Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS)](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html/187-1923024-7619234) is a specific service for people who sell on Amazon.com.  It provides sellers with an API through which they can access their Amazon account from within their own computing systems.

Comment: Is MWS still active? It seems it hasn't been updated in years https://developer.amazonservices.ca/gp/mws/api.html/178-3827115-5756723?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latest